# Power BI - How to Plot Individual Data Points on Same Day, No Summing or Averaging

Tags: powerbi

I am a new Power BI user, I come from using SQL queries and Excel formulas to plot my data. I need to create line charts that show every individual value from my data table that I have filtered for, even though there are multiple values for the same thing on the same day at the same time (say one value of 5 and one value of 1, at the same time). It is scientific data and we are required to show each value and cannot average.

I have looked at about ~20 guides online, and have it to the point where it is just summing data by day. I need to get it to no summing at all of any kind. If it makes a difference this data is coming directly from an Oracle DB and not an Excel workbook.

Here's what I have done so far: Date_Time field in X-axis set to show as Date_Time, turned off creating Date Hierarchies in data options. In the Data tab, Summarization is on "Don't Summarize" for both Date_Time and Values columns. In Visualizations pane, X-axis (Dates) has Type set to  Continuous instead of Category. Tried creating a new column in the Data Tab populated by a measure that spits out the Values into the column, both just as Values and using IF HASONEVALUE show Values, but Power BI still SUMS or COUNT_OFs the measure when I plot it, and does not have a "Don't Summarize" option in the tooltip on the Visualizations pane.

Is there a setting I am missing, or a way to do this with measures in DAX? Extremely grateful to anyone that can help.

I've included an example of the type of trend we want to show, where there could be multiple data points stacked on the same day.

[image: Trend Plot]

Comment: Do you have some sample data?